Why ollama embed response not equals /api/embeddings response?
I added embedding model from hugging face to my local ollama with this Modelfile:
FROM /home/user/hugging_face/sbert_large_nlu_ru

PARAMETER stop "<|im_start|>"
PARAMETER stop "<|im_end|>"
TEMPLATE """
<|im_start|>system
{{ .System }}<|im_end|>
<|im_start|>user
{{ .Prompt }}<|im_end|>
<|im_start|>assistant
"""

Checked it's response in Postman:

And now use this model in my python project. I'm using ollama-python https://github.com/ollama/ollama-python. Here is my simple code:
from ollama import Client
client = Client(host='http://192.168.70.79:11434')
response = client.embed(model='sbert_large_nlu_ru:latest', input='Привет')

print(response)

And here is response:

As i can see embeddings are different. Why? What can i miss there?

Can you calculate dot product btw these two vectors, to actually see how different these are;example: import numpy as np \n a = [[2, 1], [0, 3]] \n b = [[1, 1], [3, 2]] \n print(np.dot(a, b))
